# Something is wrong with Visual Studio Code syntax highlighting or simply the text display

Tags: visual-studio-code

I don't know how to describe my problem except via picture.

Don't judge my code, but if you look between the letters you will see random bits of characters. This Doesn't seem to effect how it compiles and runs, but I really want it to go away.

I've tried restarting visual studio code, closing the document withing visual studio code and reopening, and restarting my computer. Beyond that, I have no ideas. I think this problem may have started when I elected to install C/C++ Intellisense. 
[a Screenshot of my Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ivlrh.png)

fyi: I don't know how to word my problem in a way that helps google take me to relevant sources.

Comment: If this is on a PC have you check if your video driver needs updating?

Comment: I don't have problems with it outside of Visual studio code, but I'm running a PC that dual boots between Windows and Ubuntu. Currently I'm in Ubuntu. Ubuntu says I'm currently up to date on my updates.